# How can you compare an image generated by random in Java?

Tags: java, swingx

So I'm making a mini game called Rock,Paper,and Scissors in java using Swing. [image]

How can I compare my user(left) image  to the computer(right) generated image? So that I can put on a JLabel in the middle stating whether "You Win!" or "You Lose!" or "DRAW!"?

Here's my code I'm trying to figuring out how to enable my comparison of the image:

```
btrock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        user.setIcon(new ImageIcon("ROCK LEFT.PNG"));
        int index = (int) (Math.random() * (images.length - 0));
        computer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(images[index]));
        String blah = new Integer(index).toString();
        if(user.getIcon() == computer.getIcon(images[index])){
            lbl1.setText("DRAW!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have to compare images, you have to compare indexes of what you have selected and what the random() generated. And that are simple integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for beginners you could map your Images with an according enum. then you can easily compare the values of the gesture instead of comparing images.

```
enum Gesture {ROCK, SCISSOR; PAPER}

Map<Gesture, ImageIcon> leftImages;
Map<Gesture, ImageIcon> rightImages;

Gesture rightGesture;
Gesture leftGesture;

void setLeftGesture(Gesture gesture) {
    leftGesture = gesture;
    setLeftImage(leftImages.get(gesture);
}

//TODO
void setRightGesture(...);

boolean isEqualGesture(){
    return rightGesture == leftGesture;
}

boolean leftWins(){
    return rightGesture == Gesture.ROCK && leftGesture == Gesture.PAPER;
}

//TODO
boolean rightWins(){...}
```

so whenever you set your gesture left or right you simply call these code snippets above.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //let's assume we are on rocks:
    setLeft(Gesture.ROCK);
    setRight(randomGesture());

    if(isEqualGesture()) {
        //write "draw" in your text box
    }else if(leftWins()){
        //player did win, write a notification
    }else if(rightWins()){
        //computer did win
    }
}
```

### possible implementations

create a map:

```
Map<Gesture, ImageIcon> rightImages = new HashMap<>();
ImageIcon rightRock = new ImageIcon...//i don't know that part of your implementations
ImageIcon rightScissor = ...
ImageIcon rightPaper = ...
rightImages.put(Gesture.ROCK, rightRock);
rightImages.put(Gesture.SCISSOR, rightScissor);
rightImages.put(Gesture.PAPER, rightPaper);
```

the same applies for the left images. The setting up of the map should happen in the very beginning of your app. Doing so has the effect, that you load the images **ONLY ONCE** and can re-use them **again and again**. Best practice would be to create a `init()` methode, where you do all the setup stuff...

Comment: is `Gesture` the proper english term??? I can't speak english very good...

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with this line: Map<Gesture,Image> leftImages; should I put my images here?

Comment: yes - you need to create a instance of that map and fill it with images, may i suggest a `HashMap`?

Comment: i'm sooo sorry, i just realized you use `ImageIcon` instead of `Image` - my bad, i just corrected that in my answer.